# TSQL: Execute a SP within a function, which is called in select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SP *get_customer_info* in database **db_customers_ws** that is called from a webservice,
I need to fetch man's all phone numbers as well, which is 0..N, from another database **db_customers_data**.

*[db_customers_ws].[dbo].[get_human_info]*:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_customer_info 
    ...
    select col1
    ,col2
    ,getDataFromAnotherDatabase(@id)
```

I want to get data as a concatenated string, so I make a function call
*[db_customers_ws].[dbo].[getDataFromAnotherDatabase]* :

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getDataFromAnotherDatabase]  
    returns nvarchar(4000)  
    as...

    @proc = [get_data_db_server] + '.[myproc]' -- [db_customers_data.[dbo].[get_phone_numbers_string]
    exec @proc
    @arg1=@arg1,
    @arg2='meh'
```

> Error Number: 557 Error Message: Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function. Error Severity: 16 Error State: 2 Error Line: 81 Error Proc: **get_customer_info**

Could you suggest me some way of solving the error?
*If its not possible, maybe you've a clue of how can I achieve this result by other means?*

*Thank you*

Answer (score 0):

Can u describe myproc   function ?

It seems you need a join between the 2 databases.
Its not a problem if you do something like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_customer_info 
    ...
    select A.col1
    ,A.col2
    ,B.Phone1 + B.Phone2
    from db_customers_ws.dbo.get_human_info A
    join db_customers_data.dbo.UNKNOWNTABLENAME B
    on A.EmpoyeeID = B.EmpoyeeID
```

Hope it works...

Comment: myproc is a stored procedure which has an output parameter with the data I need.
Database join statement would be nice, but is it achievable if the databases might not even be on the same server? I am calling a procedure [get_data_db_server]  which takes care of routing me to corrent database

Comment: Yeah, it will work if you use a linked server. Look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35943/How-to-Config-Linked-Servers-in-a-Minute